# sticky menu doesn't respect resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a responsive web page, and a sticky menu located first on the middle of the page or so. When I scroll and the menu reaches the top it becomes fixed. This works just fine, the problem is that when I'm resizing the content above the menu becomes less high of course, so when I scroll back again the menu doesn't become sticky when I reach the top, because it still believes that the content above is on the same level as before resizing, and doesn't notice that the content resized. So the menu becomes sticky not when it reaches the top, unless it is way past the top. It takes a few moments to go sticky. If I refresh the browser this problem doesn't show, it only shows when I'm resizing. I want to know if there is any solution for the menu to respect the resizing? This is my code:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href='#about'>
          About
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='work.html'>
          Work
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#services'>
          Services
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#contact'>
          Contact
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>


    header {
      background-color: white;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      /*  box-shadow: 1px 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
      padding: .5em 0;
    }
    header h1 {
      display: none;
    }
    header ul {
      text-align: center;
    }
    header ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    header ul li a {
      padding: 1.08em 0.3em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #01486b;
      font-size: .8em;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    header ul li a:hover {
      color: #139ee3;
    }
    .padding
    {
      padding: 3.61em 0 0 0;
    }



      function navigate(e) {
        var element = $(this).attr('href');
        var where = $(element).offset().top-71.5;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:where},1000,'swing');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      $('nav a').on('click', navigate);



      var offset = $('header').offset().top;
      function changeClass(e) {
        var countScroll = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
        if (countScroll >= offset) {
          $('header').addClass('fixed_menu');
          $('main').addClass('padding');
        } else {
          $('header').removeClass('fixed_menu');
          $('main').removeClass('padding');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      $(document).on('scroll',changeClass);
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: Recompute your position inside the [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize) event handler.

Comment: please can you be more specific, im new on jquery so i dont know where to locate the window.onresize on my code

Answer (score 0):

**use:**

```
var countScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
```

**Instead of**

```
var countScroll = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
```

Comment: its the same, unless i try it but didnt works at all, that its not the problem

Comment: can you put here any link of your demo.